# Android SQLite queries marked as Error by Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

In one of my Android apps I use some `SQLite` queries that are starting to give problems since I've updated to `Android Studio 3.0`.

Despite I can compile and run the app they are marked as error.

These are the queries.

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table1 (…) ... substr(replace(table2.field2, ',', ''), table1.field1, 1) … FROM table1 … WHERE …");
```

gives error in 'replace':

> ')' or expression expected, got 'replace'

I think this would work because `replace` returns a `String`.

And:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.rowid IN (…)");
```

gives error in 'rowid':

> column name or table name expected, got 'rowid'

I think this would work too because `SQLite` adds an implicit `rowid` to each table.

And:

```
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE ? as newDB", new String[] { getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME_NEW).getPath() });
```

gives error in '?':

> expression expected, got '?'

I've changed this query to this:

```
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '"+getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME_NEW).getPath()+"' as newDB");
```

Also:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE table1 SET field1=0 WHERE field2 IN 
(SELECT field2 FROM table2 WHERE field3 LIKE '%blablabla%' OR field4 LIKE '%blebleble%' OR (field5 LIKE '%bliblibli%' AND field6 NOT LIKE '%blobloblo%') 
COLLATE NOCASE)");
```

Which gives these errors:

In 'field6 NOT LIKE':

> ')' or '.' expected, got 'NOT'

In 'NOCASE)':

> BETWEEN, IN or semicolon expected, got ')'

I don't know what is wrong with this one.

**Are these queries correct?** In iOS are identical and they are working well.

UPDATE:

These are the full queries (unfortunately due to my client's security policy I have to change the name of the tables and fields, but I hope is ok to detect the errors).

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14) " +
                    "SELECT t6.field1, t7.field2, t3.field4, t3.field5, CASE WHEN t5.field1='1' THEN '11' " +
                    "WHEN t5.field1='2' THEN '22' WHEN t5.field1='3' THEN '33' WHEN t5.field1='4' THEN '44' " +
                    "ELSE t5.field1 END AS newfield1, t4.field1, CASE WHEN t2.field1 = '0' THEN t4.field2 " +
                    "ELSE substr(replace(t4.field3, ',', ''), t2.field1, 1) END AS newfield2, t2.field4, '0', -1, '0', '1', -1, t8.field1 " +
                    "FROM table2 AS t2, table3 AS t3, table4 AS t4, table5 AS t5, table6 AS t6, table7 AS t7, table8 AS t8 " +
                    "WHERE t2.field2=t3.field3 AND t2.field3=t4.field1 AND t2.field3=t5.field2 AND t3.field2=t7.field2 AND " +
                    "t3.field1=t6.field1 AND substr(t5.field1, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4') AND substr(t5.field1, 2, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4') AND t2.field5=t8.field2");

db.execSQL("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.rowid IN (SELECT table1.rowid FROM table1, table4 AS t4 WHERE table1.field6=t4.field1 AND (((t4.field2 NOT LIKE '%%' || substr(table1.field5, 1,1) || '%%') AND (t4.field3 NOT LIKE '%%' || substr(table1.field5, 1,1) || '%%')) OR ((t4.field2 NOT LIKE '%%' || substr(table1.field5, 2,1) || '%%') AND (t4.field3 NOT LIKE '%%' || substr(table1.field5, 2,1) || '%%'))))");

db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE ? as newDB", new String[] { getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME_NEW).getPath() });
Changed to:
db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '"+getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME_NEW).getPath()+"' as newDB");
And the error is gone.

db.execSQL("UPDATE table1 SET field13=1 WHERE field2 IN (SELECT t7.field2 FROM table7 AS t7 WHERE t7.field1='Text1' OR t7.field1='Text2' OR t7.field1 LIKE '%TEXT3%' OR t7.field1 LIKE '%TEXT4%' OR t7.field1 LIKE '%TEXT5%' OR t7.field1 LIKE '%TEXT6%' OR (t7.field1 LIKE '%TEXT7%' AND t7.field1 NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%') COLLATE NOCASE)");
```

Comment: can you post the full queries ?

Comment: What Android version have you configured?

Comment: I have configured Android 23 (6.0). Regarding to the full queries I'll try to post them.

Comment: @Wonton can you post your query as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Wonton Here is a suggestion use MVP design this is where you have a Database Model where you have a bunch of get and set for each item in the database table.
Next handle all your CRUD in an Activity called DBHelper then you can make calls to it from any other Activity with a lot less chance of errors. YES I use db.execSQL but once you have the string to update or insert in DBHelper life is good Here is an example of code from a DBHelper Activity HINT read about MVP

```
    /* Update Record in Database*/
public void updateDBRow(String rowid,String website, String username, String password, String question,String answer, String notes){

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(Col_WS,website);
    cv.put(Col_UN,username);
    cv.put(Col_PW,password);
    cv.put(Col_SQ,question);
    cv.put(Col_SA,answer);
    cv.put(Col_NOTES,notes);

    /*NOTE WHERE THE quotation MARKS ARE */
    db.update(TABLE_INFO,cv, Col_ID + " = ?",new String[] { rowid });
    db.close();
}
```